# How to write a function that returns the perimeter of a rectangle with a width of 5 and a height of 8?

Tags: javascript, function

My current attempt is below, but I am not sure where to even put the inputs of 5 and 8. Any help/advice is apprecaited.

```
function rectPerimeter(width, height) {
  return 2 * width + 2 * height;
}

console.log(rectPerimeter)
```

Comment: `rectPerimeter(5, 8)` to call the function. You may want to review function calls, because they're quite an important concept in programming.

Comment: Thanks  @Carcigenicate !! I am still getting a grasp on the fundamentals, I am 1 week in. Do you have any insight if you were to take this a step further? See below:                                   
3) Write a new function that returns the perimeter of a rectangle with the width and height being specified as arguments to the function.

Comment: 3) appears to be what you've already done.

Answer (score 1):

do as follows:

```
function rectPerimeter(width, height) {
  return 2 * width + 2 * height;
}

// define width
let w = 5; // change value as you need
// define height
let h = 8; // change value as you need

// call rectPerimeter with params i.e. width and height
console.log(rectPerimeter(w, h));
```

You can also capture the return value and then show it to console:

```
function rectPerimeter(width, height) {
  return 2 * width + 2 * height;
}

// define width
let w = 5; // change value as you need
// define height
let h = 8; // change value as you need

// call rectPerimeter with params i.e. width and height
let perimeter = rectPerimeter(w, h);

// show perimeter to console
console.log(perimeter);
```

Comment: It would be more educational if the variables used as arguments were not named the same as the parameters by coincidence.

Comment: Awesome. I see my misstep was including the let bindings inside of the function while also re-using width and height as the names for my "let" variables. I am starting wrap my head around the function itself being a template that you setup to pass arguments into, and organizing it as such. I appreciate your help @reyad !

Comment: @DobsonDunavant If this answer solves your problem then please mark this answer as answered.